# Drawing the very first dot on a drawing app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitouch, cgpoint

When I want to  make a dot on the canvas, it doesn't appear. Even when I do a single touch, it's as if the program doesn't receive the first CGPoint value. Only when I move my finger do the point values appear (for example: (190.0, 375.5), (135, 234), ...)

> DV.swift

```
class DV: UIView {
var lines: [Line] = []
var firstPoint: CGPoint!
var lastPoint: CGPoint!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    lastPoint = touches.first!.locationInView(self)
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var newPoint = touches.first!.locationInView(self)

    lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
    lastPoint = newPoint

    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
   // print("fine") starts at beginning only

    for line in lines {

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context,line.start.x , line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)

    }
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

> Line.swift // My line initializer

```
class Line {
var start: CGPoint
var end: CGPoint

init(start _start: CGPoint, end _end: CGPoint) {
    start = _start
    end = _end
}
}
```

Comment: Before looking at your code more in depth: have you simply tried adding `print`-statements to the functions you are interested in? Especially when doing custom graphics, debugging and logging output are quite important for tracking down issues.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `touchesBegan`... the program is receiving your touches all right, it's just you're not doing any drawing. You don't call `setNeedsDisplay`, and your drawing code assumes complete line segments anyway (not single points).

Comment: Yes, when I move my finger around, it prints out all the points that were traced by my finger. But it doesn't print out the first value , or the dot in this case. My guess is that it only receives values when I move my finger only. But I don't know whether or not there's an extra variable that should be created to represent that dot; or if it's already in my list of points that I haven't placed into my canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only using `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`, not `touchesEnded`, so if the touch doesn't move and then ends you are basically ignoring it. You need to implement `touchesEnded` to commit the drawing changes and draw them.